# Importing already existing git repo with multiple branches and tags into gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm trying to import an already existing git repository with multiple branches and tags into gerrit. I'm following the official guide at https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install-quick.html#_already_existing_project.

However, when issuing the push command all the branches and tags, except "master" which I'm currently in, are "prohibited by Gerrit". The output is something like this:

```
user@host:~/my-project$ git push ssh://user@localhost:29418/demo-project *:*
[....]
* [new branch]      master -> master
! [remote rejected] origin/Branch1 -> origin/Branch1 (prohibited by Gerrit)
! [remote rejected] origin/Branch2 -> origin/Branch2 (prohibited by Gerrit)
[....]
! [remote rejected] Tag1 -> Tag1 (prohibited by Gerrit)
! [remote rejected] Tag2 -> Tag2 (prohibited by Gerrit)
[....]
```

I'm administrator so it shouldn't be an access rights issue.

**Update:**
By using blahdiblah's script (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095671/63661) I was successful with moving all the branches.
To be able to transfer all the tags, I first had to give the group Administrators the *"Create Reference"* permission for *refs/tags/** using the gerrit web interface. After that i could push them using *git push  --tags*.

Answer (score 6):

The minimal set of permissions to allow for `refs/*` in order to import an existing repository to Gerrit was for us:

- `Create Reference` (quite obviously)
- `Forge Author Identity` and `Forge Committer Identity` (because you are pushing other people's commits)
- `Push` (quite obviously)
- `Push Merge Commit` (this is not included in `Push`, and you'll likely have merge commits)
- `Push Annotated Tag` (we use annotations in some tags)

You also need to allow `Push Signed Tag` if you have signed tags, obviously.

Finally, if you plan to run the import more than once to incrementally sync repositories during some transition period, you also need to allow `Read` and enable `Force Push` for all `Push` permissions.