# merging the changes from two repositories in github

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo for a project. Since there were some issues in the codebase and it was hard to identify and fix, to meet the deadline I create a new project on my local machine and started to re develop the entire application. After developing, I ran the `git init` command and then ran the `git remote add origin <path to the original repo>`.

When I try to push the changes, git did not allow me to push the changes and the message I got was `you need to at least perform a single commit`. I somehow had to secure my changes and created another temporary repo on the serve and finally pushed my changes to the new repo.

I need to move my new repo changes to my original repo and preferably on a new branch. How can I get this done? Please let me know the steps to get this done.

Comment: Did you commit your work before trying to push the changes?  There may be multiple problems going on here.

Comment: I have committed the changes to the local repository before pushing the changes.

Comment: Use `git push -u oldrepo branchname` from the new repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem for git. Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818927/git-push-branch-from-one-remote-to-another). For you, this would be:

```
cd <<original_repo>>
git remote add new_repo <<url_to_new_repo>>
git fetch new_repo
git push origin refs/remotes/new_repo/master:refs/heads/new_repo_master
```

This will create a new branch in `origin` called `new_repo_master` that contains the commits from the `master` branch in your new repository.

Answer (score 0):

There are available two possible solutions,

#### Submodules

Either copy repository A into separate directory in larger project B, or (perhaps better) clone repository A into subdirectory in project B.  Then use [git submodule](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.5.6/git-submodule.html) to make this repository a ***submodule*** of a repository B.

This is a good solution for loosely-coupled repositories, where development in repository A continues, and major portion of development is separate stand-alone development in A.  See also [SubmoduleSupport](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/SubmoduleSupport) and [GitSubmoduleTutorial](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial) pages on Git Wiki.

#### Subtree merge

You can merge repository A into a subdirectory of a project B using the ***subtree merge*** strategy. This is described in [*Subtree Merging and You*](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/subtree-merging-and-you/) by Markus Prinz.

```
git remote add -f Bproject /path/to/B
git merge -s ours --no-commit Bproject/master
git read-tree --prefix=dir-B/ -u Bproject/master
git commit -m "Merge B project as our subdirectory"
git pull -s subtree Bproject master
```

Or you can use **git subtree** tool ([repository on github](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree)) by apenwarr (Avery Pennarun), announced for example in his blog post [A new alternative to git submodules: git subtree](http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=200904#30).

---

*I think in your case (A is to be part of larger project B) the correct solution would be to use **subtree merge***