# Push all remote source branches to another remote source

Tags: git

How can I push all branches to a remote?
If I have a project with two remotes, and I want to pull all remote branches from one of the sources and push it back to the second remote source.
How can I do that without checking out all branches locally?

## Short question

how can I push all of the remotes/origin* into origin2 remote?

```
git remote -v
# origin  /project1 (fetch)
# origin  /project1 (push)
# origin2 /project3 (fetch)
# origin2 /project3 (push)

git branch -a
# * master
#   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
#   remotes/origin/feature1
#   remotes/origin/feature2
#   remotes/origin/feature3
#   remotes/origin/master
```

trying to use:

```
git push origin2 --all
# Everything up-to-date
```

Does not make the work, it says "Everything up-to-date" because nothing was locally modified.

## Full example

(code is copy/paste executable, output is commented out with #):

suppose I create a project with just the master branch:

```
project1_dir=/project1

mkdir ${project1_dir}
cd ${project1_dir}
git init 
touch file
git add file
git commit -m "file"
git log --graph --oneline --all

# * 46734b5 (HEAD -> master) file
```

and then I cloned, using:

```
project2_dir=/project2
project3_dir=/project3

git clone ${project1_dir} ${project2_dir}
git clone ${project1_dir} ${project3_dir}
```

and I set /project3 to be a remote source of /project2

```
cd ${project2_dir}
git remote add origin2 ${project3_dir}
```

so far we have:

```
cd /project1
git log --graph --oneline --all

# * 46734b5 (HEAD -> master) file

cd /project2
git log --graph --oneline --all

# * 46734b5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) file

cd /project3
git log --graph --oneline --all

# * 46734b5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) file
```

and then I create several branches on /project1

```
# simply create some branches
cd ${project1_dir}
features="feature1 feature2 feature3"
for feature in ${features}; do
    echo Creating ${feature} branch
    git branch ${feature} master
    git checkout ${feature}
    touch ${feature}
    git add ${feature}
    git commit -m "commit ${feature}"
done
```

and pull them to /project2:

```
cd ${project2_dir}
git fetch origin
git branch -a
# * master
#   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
#   remotes/origin/feature1
#   remotes/origin/feature2
#   remotes/origin/feature3
#   remotes/origin/master
```

Then I try to push everything to /project3: (and here is where I would need the help)

```
git push origin2 --all
# Everything up-to-date
```

But that does not work:

```
cd ${project3_dir}
git branch -a
# * master
#   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
#   remotes/origin/master
```

here is the full script: 
https://pastebin.com/P7zs68Sc

Comment: You can probably use something like `git push origin2 refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*` or similar, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: Looks like I was right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21133502

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes, that does the trick. thanks