# Tagging a remote git repo without cloning it

Tags: git, tags

Is there a way to tag a remote git repository without having cloned it locally?

In order to correlate a code repository with a config repository, I want to (as a CI build step) tag whatever is the current head of the config repository with build-n (where N is the current build number provided by jenkins).

The config repository isn't used as part of the build, I simply want an easy way to fetch the config revision as it was when for example version 1234 was built, and tagging it as "build-1234" seems like the simplest way to achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tag a remote git repository without cloning it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922700/tag-a-remote-git-repository-without-cloning-it)

Answer (score 0):

git tags are created locally and pushed from your local repo to the remote repo.
You could however, connect to the remote repo from a bash shell for instance, and create the tag directly on that repo without actually needing a local copy.

```
cd \path\to\remote\git\repo
git tag -a v1234 -m 'Version 1234'
```